# Finding the median of a probability distribution

Tags: probability

A gambler makes a long sequence of bets against a rich friend. The gambler has initial capital C. On each round, a coin is tossed; if the coin comes up tails, he loses 30% of his current capital, but if the coin comes up heads he instead wins 35% of his current capital. Let $C_n$ be the gambler's capital after n rounds and write $C_n$ as a product $C*Y_1*Y_2*...*Y_n$.

Find the median of the distribution of $C_{(10)}$ and compare it to the expectation of $C_{(10)}$.

I worked out that the expectation of $C_n$ is $1.025^nC$ so I can calculate expectations but I'm a bit confused about finding the median.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry the median has half heads and half tails. Each head/tail combination leads to a multiplication of capital by $(1.35)(0.70)=0.945$.

Comment: so then is the median $0.945C$?

Comment: It is $(0.945)^5C$.

Comment: yes sorry got that a second after i posted that message! thanks